# Spring integration JdbcPollingChannelAdapter with configurable Select and Update SQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

The Spring Integration JdbcPollingChannelAdapter jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter allows you to use a SqlParameterSource to change the values in the selectQuery WHERE clause.  However there is no mechanism to change the actual SQL.  The adapter's constructor takes the selectQuery:String which can not be overridden or updated.

My requirement is such that a different SELECT (& UPDATE) is required based on the mode the application is running in.  And the mode will change at runtime.

Is there a mechanism by which I could achieve this with the SI components?

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is currently not supported (you can set the initial value with a place holder property, but you can't change it once set).

You can use a regular POJO inbound channel adapter with a `JdbcTemplate` as a work around.

Feel free to [open a new Feature Suggestion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues).

Something like

```
public JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(JdbcOperations jdbcOperations, Supplier<String> selectQuery) {
```

should be easy enough to implement.

Comment: You can have several `jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter` configurations according your queries requirements and start/stop them when this or that mode is enable in your application. See `Control Bus` for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#control-bus

Comment: Thanks both.  I am looking at the most suitable of these workarounds for my requirements, and have raised an enhancement in the meantime:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3072